# How do I diagnose whether SMB access with Windows Server 2003 server and Windows Server 2008 R2 client is actually slow?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, server-message-block

We have a file server in our web hosting environment that runs Windows Server 2003 SP2. The web servers all need to access this common file server to retrieve some files. The web servers that are also running Windows Server 2003 SP2 seem to work fine, but the web servers running Windows Server 2008 R2 encounter more page timeouts on pages that need to access the common file server.

In this scenario, Windows Server 2008 is the client and Windows Server 2003 is the server, so according to http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/05/30/two-minute-drill-overview-of-smb-2-0.aspx I would think that we're using SMB 1.0.

Are there tools I can use to determine if the SMB access from the Windows Server 2008 server is indeed slower? Could the negotiation of which version of SMB to use be the cause of slower file access? If I can rule out the SMB speed, I'll focus my attention elsewhere, but the pages that are slow seem to be those that access the shared filesystem.